# How to delete slash from the str?

Tags: regex, perl

How to delete slash from the str? Need the solution on perl.
I tried

```
        ($phot) = $photos =~ s/\///g;
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a diagnostic message from Perl. What actually happened? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 10):

In Perl, the `s///` operator modifies the string you apply it to; so, you should write:

```
my $phot = $photos;
$phot =~ s/\///g;
```

or, more tersely:

```
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s/\///g;
```

In recent versions of Perl, there's a flag `/r` that you can use, to get a behavior more like what you're expecting:

```
my $phot = ($photos =~ s/\///gr);
```

but you'll have to check if your version of Perl has it. (You can run `perl -v` to see what version of Perl you have. This feature was introduced in Perl v5.14.0.)

---

**Edited to add:** As [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) points out in a comment, and [Ωmega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215106/mega) implies in his/her answer, the `s///` operator allows a delimiter other than `/`; so, for example, any of these will work:

```
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s{/}{}g;
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s#/##g;
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s'/''g;        # note: prevents variable interpolation
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s-/--g;
```

One of these might be more clear than writing `s/\///g`. (This is up to you.)

This freedom to choose your delimiter is true of all of the quote-like operators; for example, `"x"` can also be written as `qq{x}` or `qq/x/` or `qq-x-`. For more information, see ["Quote and Quote-like Operators" in the `perlop` man-page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: Also, `s/\///` is horrid and qualifies for obfuscated code. The use of a different delimiter, eg `s{/}{}` can make the regex easier to read.

Comment: @amon: I think "horrid" and "obfuscated" is a bit of an exaggeration, but you're right, a different delimiter might be easier to read. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TLP, I've always seen it called "leaning toothpick syndrome".

Comment: Indeed that might be the full designation.

Answer (score 0):

```
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s#/##g;
```

or

```
(my $phot = $photos) =~ s{/}{}g;
```